# Normalizing the data from denormalized table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in my table like this

```
RepID|Role|Status|StartDate |EndDate   |
-----|----|------|----------|----------|  
10001|R1  |Active|01/01/2015|01/31/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R1  |Leavee|02/01/2015|02/12/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R1  |Active|02/13/2015|02/28/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R2  |Active|03/01/2015|03/18/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R2  |Leave |03/19/2015|04/10/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R2  |Active|04/11/2015|05/10/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R1  |Active|05/11/2015|06/13/2015|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
10001|R1  |Leave |06/14/2015|12/31/9998|
-----|----|------|----------|----------|
```

I am looking for the output like this,

```
RepID|Role|StartDate |EndDate   |   
-----|----|----------|----------|
10001|R1  |01/01/2015|02/28/2015|
-----|----|----------|----------|  
10001|R2  |03/01/2015|05/10/2015|
-----|----|----------|----------|  
10001|R1  |05/11/2015|12/31/9998|
-----|----|----------|----------|
```

Whenever only the role change happens, I need to capture the start and EndDate. I tried different ways but couldn't get the output.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the SQL i tried with but it doesnt help,

```
SELECT T1.RepID, T1.Role, Min(T1.StartDate)     AS StartDate,     Max(T1.EndDate) AS    EndDate
FROM
 (SELECT rD1.RepID, rD1.Role, rD1.StartDate, rD1.EndDate 
FROM repDetails rD1
INNER JOIN repDetails rD2
    ON rD2.RepID = rD1.RepID AND rD2.StartDate = DateAdd (Day, 1, rD1.EndDate)      AND (rD2.Role = rD1.Role OR (rD2.Role IS NULL AND rD1.Role IS NULL)         OR (rD2.Role = '' AND rD1.Role = ''))

UNION

SELECT rD2.RepID, rD2.Role, rD2.StartDate, rD2.EndDate 
FROM repDetails rD1
INNER JOIN repDetails rD2
    ON rD2.RepID = rD1.RepID AND rD2.StartDate = DateAdd (Day, 1, rD1.EndDate)      AND (rD2.Role = rD1.Role OR (rD2.Role IS NULL AND rD1.Role IS NULL)         OR (rD2.Role = '' AND rD1.Role = ''))
    ) T1
GROUP BY T1.RepID, T1.Role

UNION

SELECT EP.RepID, EP.Role AS DataValue, EP.StartDate,    EP.EndDate
FROM repDetails EP
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT rD1.RepID, rD1.Role, rD1.StartDate, rD1.EndDate 
FROM repDetails rD1
INNER JOIN repDetails rD2
    ON rD2.RepID = rD1.RepID AND rD2.StartDate = DateAdd (Day, 1, rD1.EndDate)      AND (rD2.Role = rD1.Role OR (rD2.Role IS NULL AND rD1.Role IS NULL)         OR (rD2.Role = '' AND rD1.Role = ''))

UNION

SELECT rD2.RepID, rD2.Role ,    rD2.StartDate, rD2.EndDate 
FROM repDetails rD1
INNER JOIN repDetails rD2
    ON rD2.RepID = rD1.RepID AND rD2.StartDate = DateAdd (Day, 1, rD1.EndDate)      AND (rD2.Role = rD1.Role OR (rD2.Role IS NULL AND rD1.Role IS NULL)         OR (rD2.Role = '' AND rD1.Role = ''))
    ) T1
ON EP.RepID = T1.RepID AND EP.StartDate =   T1.StartDate
WHERE T1.RepID IS NULL
```

Comment: What are the ways you tried? What was the output?

Comment: This would be tricky with a basic query - maybe a SQL guru here could do it, but it would be very simple using a stored procedure.

Comment: I cannot use any stored procedure in the application. I tried with MAX and MIN function something like the below SQL.

Comment: the above SQL doesnt return the output in the way I wanted.

Comment: @Naveen, Please, don’t put your code in the comments, edit the question to include the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to identify continuous rows until the role changes. This can be done by comparing the next row's role using the `lead` function and some additional logic to categorize all the previous rows into the same group.

After classifying them into groups, you just need to use `min` and `max` to get the start and end dates.

```
with groups as (
select x.*
,case when grp = 1 then 0 else 1 end + sum(grp) over(partition by repid order by startdate) grps
from (select t.*
      ,case when lead(role) over(partition by repid order by startdate) = role then 0 else 1 end grp
      from t) x
)
select distinct repid,role
,min(startdate) over(partition by repid,grps) startdt
,max(enddate) over(partition by repid,grps) enddt
from groups
order by 1,3
```

[**`Sample demo`**](http://rextester.com/DDS59776)

Comment: Thank you VKP, This worked great!! I didn't know about the over function!!

Comment: @VKP, why did you use select distinct/over in the 2nd statement instead of grouping by your grps value?

Comment: @Beth..because each id and role combination can have different start and end dates..`min() over()` or `max() over()` without `group by` return all the rows in the data. To avoid this i used `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

do you just want the min(start) / max(end) dates for each repID and role?
If so, try:

```
Select
  repID, role,
  min(starDate),
  max(endDate)
from
  tbl
group by 
  repID, role
```

--
A more verbose solution, equivalent to VKP's:

```
SELECT
    repid, ROLE, grpID, 
    MIN(startdate) AS min_startDateOverRole, 
    MAX(endDate) AS max_endDateOverRole  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        *, CASE WHEN isGrpEnd = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end + 
        -- when on group end row, don't increment grpID.  
        -- Wait until start of next group
        SUM(isGrpEnd) OVER(ORDER BY startdate) grpID  
        -- sum(all group end rows up to this one)
     FROM 
            (SELECT 
                *,
               CASE WHEN lead(ROLE) OVER(ORDER BY startdate) = ROLE 
                         THEN 0 ELSE 1 end isGrpEnd
             FROM t) x  )
GROUP BY 
  repid, ROLE, grpid
ORDER BY 
  1,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Beth!! I just dont want the min or max based the rep and role.. Whenever the Role changes for the Rep, I need the start and end date in one record to see how long they are in that role.